# Error while compiling botan sample example in Qt

Tags: qt, cryptography, hash, botan

I am trying to find out the error for two days but still haven't got this unknown reason figure out.

I have configured and compiled Botan library. Everything goes ok but when try to write this sample code to be run..

```
S2K* s2k = get_s2k("PBKDF2(SHA-256)");
s2k->set_iterations(4049);
SecureVector<byte> key_and_IV = s2k->derive_key(48, passphrase).bits_of();
SymmetricKey key(key_and_IV, 32);
```

it says error: 'class Botan::PBKDF' has no member named 'set_iterations'

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't use the Botan library, but looking at [the documentation](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/namespaceBotan.html#a5612cc6316fbfb5d5a5b100c9cf7064e), it looks like `get_s2k()` has been deprecated in favour of `get_pbkdf()`. What version of the library are you using?

Comment: i am using current stable version 1.10....should I use old version than ??

Answer (score 1):

The Botan docs for v1.11.1 report that the function `get_s2k()` has been deprecated, recommending that you use [`get_pbkdf()`](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/namespaceBotan.html#aff3f24dde647603d5c06d80dc11fcacb) instead.

According to the docs, `get_sdk(algospec)` just returns the result of a call to `get_pbkdf(algo_spec)` which will give you a pointer to an instance of the `class` [`Botan::PBKDF`](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1PBKDF.html).

First things first then, your code needs to be something more like:

```
PBKDF *s2k = getpbkdf("PBKDF2(SHA-256)");
```

Unfortunately without knowing what you want to do with `s2k` I can't help any further, as the docs have no reference to a public member function of `PBKDF` called `set_iterations()`. You're getting the error you mention because `Botan::PBKDF` really does have no member named `set_iterations`. You need to read the docs, work out what the purpose of `set_iterations()` was in your now deprecated example and hence how to achieve that purpose in the newer version of the library.

Comment: Can you link us to where you found your sample code? That might help shed some light :)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you missed your library header... as your error message says: 'has no member named...'